Custom environment results in "Extraneous input"
Motivation
I am using the package plantuml to plot uml diagrams. Unfortunately, the default style of plantuml (the tool) is ugly and I need to define a custom style in every plantuml environment. To avoid repeating the style definition often, I want to define a custom environment which uses the plantuml environment and already includes the style. Unfortunately, I get some errors (details further below).
Workaround found - no solution required anymore
I found out that plantuml supports themes. These contain all styling I need and can be added in one line - which is acceptable to me even if it is repeated.
For learning purposes, I would still be interested in ideas, but I do not need them anymore to solve the original problem.
MWE with standard usage of plantuml
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{plantuml}

\begin{document}

\begin{plantuml}
    @startuml % required by plantuml (the tool, not the package)
    skinparam sequence { % style definition
        ParticipantBorderColor black
        ParticipantBackgroundColor white
    }

    Alice -> Bob: test % diagram content
    @enduml
\end{plantuml}

\end{document}

My approach
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{plantuml}

% environment definition
\newenvironment{bplantuml}{
\begin{plantuml}
@startuml
skinparam sequence {
ParticipantBorderColor black
ParticipantBackgroundColor white
}
}{
@enduml
\end{plantuml}
}

\begin{document}

% usage
\begin{bplantuml}
    Alice -> Bob: test
\end{bplantuml}

\end{document}

Error

FancyVerb Error:   Extraneous input ` @startuml skinparam sequence {
ParticipantBorderColor blac k ParticipantBackgroundColor white } '
between \begin{plantuml}[<key=value>] an d line end

Further ideas
Surrounding the environment definition with makeatletter/makeatother did not work, though I might need it anyways once the original problem is fixed?

Could you include the documentclass and appropriate packages so that your (nonworking) example is as complete as possible?  The fact that this is using FancyVerb in the background may be problematic - verbatim environments don't behave well with macros.

Of course, done

Sorry, I don't think it's possible.

Thank you for taking a look!
